# Is there a Real valued function with image of every open interval the whole real line

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function with range equal to whole reals on every open set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32126/function-with-range-equal-to-whole-reals-on-every-open-set)

Hello,

My problem is the following
"Is there a Real valued function with image of every open interval the whole real line?. Shall it exist, construct it"

I know so far that this equals finding uncountably many dense disjoint subset of R (in particular the preimages of the elements of R).

I shall be jolly thankful to anybody with a clue.

Comment: The Conway base 13 function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function

Comment: See also a previous MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32126/function-with-range-equal-to-whole-reals-on-every-open-set/32127#32127

Comment: To find uncountably many disjoint dense subsets in $\mathbb R$, you may take uncountably many real numbers that are independent over $\mathbb Q$ and then translate $\mathbb Q$ by these numbers.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the question linked by Andrey.

Comment: See also this related MO question on whether the base 13 function is a measurable function http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32641/is-conways-base-13-function-measurable