# Hausdorff dimension of level set of Conway base 13 function

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

Yesterday I had a discussion about Conway's base-13 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) function (and what fancy properties it has). During that discussion the other person explained that he pictured the level sets to look like a fractal. This got me curious and motivated the following question:

> Is it known what the Hausdorff dimension of the level sets of Conway's base-13 function is?

In case you might worry that it is not measurable (it is) see [Is Conway's base-13 function measurable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32641/is-conways-base-13-function-measurable)

Comment: Surely there are countably many preimages to each non-zero real, so that $\text{dim}_H(C^{-1}(\alpha))=0$ for any $\alpha\ne 0$. On the other hand, $C^{-1}(0)$ is a set of measure 1, so has Hausdorff dimension 1.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thank you for the answer. The second point was clear to me, but I completely missed the the first one.