# Is there a Borel-measurable function which maps every interval onto $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, examples

Using AC, one easily defines a function $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that the $F$-image of any real interval $(a,b)$ ($a<b$) is equal to $\mathbb R$. 
(Equivalently, the $F$-preimage of any real singleton has to be a dense set in $\mathbb R$.) Does there exist a Borel-measurable $F$ with this property?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function

Comment: I will just point out that such functions can be obtained even without AC, some such examples can be found in this post on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net): [Function with range equal to whole reals on every open set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/32126) and also in several posts on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790927) and other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/790927).
Functions with this property are sometimes called [strongly Darboux](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137986).

Comment: Since [Conway base 13 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) was mentioned in the first comment, I will also add link to this question: [Is Conway's base-13 function measurable?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/32641)

Answer (score 4):

This is [Exercise 9.M](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA59) from A. C. M. van Rooij, W. H. Schikhof: *A Second Course on Real Analysis*.$\newcommand{\dcc}[1]{\lfloor#1\rfloor}$

> **Exercise 9.M.** (Another function that maps every interval onto $[0,1]$) For $x\in[0,1]$ let
>   $0.x_1x_2x_3\dots$ be the standard dyadic development of $x-\dcc x$:
>   $$x_n=\dcc{2^n x}-2\dcc{2^{n-1}x}$$
>   where $\dcc x$ is the entire part of $x$. Define $\phi\colon{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ by
>   $$\phi(x)=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}n$$
>   Show that $\phi$ maps every interval *onto* $[0,1]$. (Hint: First show that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ if there exist $p,q\in\mathbb N$ such that
>   $x_p=y_q$, $x_{p+1}=y_{q+1}$, $x_{p+2}=y_{q+2}$, etc., so that it suffices to show that $\phi$ maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$. Now let $t\in[0,1]$, $t\ne1$. Find an $x\in[0,1]$ such that $x_1+\dots+x_n=\dcc{nt}$ for every $n$ and prove that $\phi(x)=t$. Finally, find an $x$ with $\phi(x)=1$.)

The same function appears as [Problem 1.3.29](https://books.google.com/books?id=UBmIAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA159) in Kaczor, Nowak: *Problems in Mathematical Analysis Vol II* and it is given also in an answer here: [Can we construct a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that it has intermediate value property and discontinuous everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21812#44285). The same function was also used by Andrés E. Caicedo as an example of a function which is of Baire class 2 but not of Baire class 1: [Examples of Baire class 2 functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/614429#614435). (See also his blog post: [414/514 Examples of Baire class two functions](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2014/11/03/414514-examples-of-baire-class-two-functions/))

As all functions $x_n$ are Borel measurable, so is the function $\phi$.

For this function, the image of a non-trivial interval is only the interval $[0,1]$. But we can get function which maps this onto reals by composition with some <s>continuous</s> Borel surjection from a unit interval to reals.

Comment: How can there be a continuous surjection from the compact interval $[0,1]$ to the reals?

Comment: @GregoryArone You're right about that. (And I should have been more careful when writing the answer.) Luckily enough, a Borel function is enough for the requirements of the asker. (For example, we can take a continuous bijection $(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ and define values at $0$ and $1$ arbitrarily.

Comment: I have to thank everybody for comprehensive answers. A bit more complex question could be to require that the $F$-preimage of every singleton be a COUNTABLE dense set.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{I_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ be the set of all open intervals with rational endpoints. Construct pairwise disjoint sets $A_n$ $(n\in\mathbb N)$ such that each $A_n$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set and $A_n\subseteq I_n$. For each $n\in\mathbb N$ define a continuous surjection $f_n:A_n\to[-n,n]$. Define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ so that $f(x)=f_n(x)$ if $x\in A_n$ and $f(x)=x$ if $x\notin\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n$. It's easy to see that $f$ is Borel measurable and maps every interval onto $\mathbb R$.

**P.S.** As [Martin Sleziak pointed out in a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347304/is-there-a-borel-measurable-function-which-maps-every-interval-onto-mathbb-r/347365#comment869731_347365) the functions $f_n$ can be chosen to be at most two-to one, in which case $f^{-1}(x)$ will be a countable dense set for each $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: If we choose the function $f_n$ in a manner similar to [Devil's staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), we get that $f^{-1}(x)$ is countable for each $x\ne0$, right? (For each $x$ we get at most two preimages inside $A_n$.) I am asking this since [Vladimir Kanovei mentioned in a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347304/is-there-a-borel-measurable-function-which-maps-every-interval-onto-mathbb-r/347365#comment869630_347305) that they would also be interested in an example where the fibers are countable dense sets.

Comment: Sounds right. Hmm. What if we define $f(x)=x$ for $x\notin\bigcup_nA_n$?